# How can I set the background color of the overflow menu in Android?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I am trying to set a custom background color to the overflow menu. However, I am unable to do so. This is what I tried:

```
<resources>

<style name="TranslucentTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TranslucentActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/transparent_black</item>
</style>

<style name="TranslucentActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/actionbar_logo_space</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) Add style to DropDownListView:

```
<style name="OdnakoDropDownListView" parent="@android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

2) Create selectable_background.xml in yours /res/drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/blue"/>

</selector>
```

3) Add item to yours theme:

```
<style name="TranslucentTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- other attributes-->
<item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/OdnakoDropDownListView</item>
</style>
```